# Mobile App Performance testing

Tags: performance, testing, mobile

Is there any performance testing tool for mobile app?  Also i am not looking for performance of App from one page to another page but i am also looking for Multiple Users?

Comment: Multiple users on the same mobile app at the same time?

Comment: Yes multiple users on the same mobile app at the same time

Comment: you can refer the Jmeter proxy setting configurations mentioned in the - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-record-ios-application-http-requests/    From Jmeter scripts can be recorded and also load can be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iPhone you can use performance tool which is provided in x-code itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the multiple users issue, you could record the HTTP traffic then replay this in a load driver. This is close to what the server sees and if you want to get closer there are WAN emulators out there that will simulate the various Wi-Fi conditions, higher latency, dropped packets etc. Most Mobile App load testing is done this way as it is difficult to have huge numbers of real Mobile users hitting your app at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

SeeTest provides monitoring infrastructure of cpu and memory of device during runtime.
Here is a link from the online guide:
http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/Monitoring1.htm